# Nullpointerexception on runOnUiThread

Tags: java, android

I'm getting error reports from users and I have no idea whats wrong with my code. The logcat is this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.laurenswuyts.find.it.MainActivity$LoadPlaces$1.run(MainActivity.java:299)
at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4244)
at com.laurenswuyts.find.it.MainActivity$LoadPlaces.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:293)
at com.laurenswuyts.find.it.MainActivity$LoadPlaces.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4697)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And it's about this piece of code:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed Places into LISTVIEW
                     * */
                    // Get json response status
                    String status = nearPlaces.status;

                    // Check for all possible status
                    if(status.equals("OK")){
                        // Successfully got places details
                        if (nearPlaces.results != null) {

                            // loop through each place
                            for (Place p : nearPlaces.results) {
```

Can anyone help me? I'm really stuck on this one ...

Comment: Can you show us line 299 of your MainActivity?

Comment: Also, it's hard to tell without referencing the line numbers as per the stack trace. My guess would be "status" is null, but it also could be nearPlaces based on this glimpse. What's on MainActivity 299?

Comment: @syb0rg than never mind, sorry :)

Comment: Mainacticity 299 is the line   String status = nearPlaces.status;

Comment: then your `nearPlaces` pointer is null :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log tells you

```
(MainActivity.java:299)
```

That means line 299 of MainActivity

As this line is:

```
String status = nearPlaces.status;
```

That just means that nearPlaces is null... There is nothing more we could do to fix that ;-)

You should initialise it with some data!